# FileZilla: Whats the best way to synch several folders into one?

Tags: ftp, sync, filezilla

I have some images on my PC several folders and (simplified) looks like this:

```
Folder1  
- file1.jpg  
- file2.jpg  
- file3.jpg

Folder2  
- 825474.jpg  
- 3684.jpg  

Folder3  

Folder4
```

And I use FileZilla to upload them into the root directory of an FTP

```
/  
  file1.jpg  
  file2.jpg  
  file3.jpg  
  825474.jpg  
  3684.jpg
```

I dragged and dropped the files inside the folder to the root directory of the FTP and this worked fine. But now I have over 80k files in about 10 folders in my PC and its getting impossible to work...
Is there a better way of doing this?

What I was picturing was some way of telling FileZilla to sync from several folders into the root directory of the FTP.

Any other solution is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open *File search* window (from toolbar);
- Select *Local search* function to generate a list of all local files;
- Select all found files;
- Right click, and select *Upload*;
- Select *Flatten local paths, upload all contained files directly into target directory*.

---

Similarly for downloads:
[Get FileZilla to ignore remote folders and just download all files in the hierarchy to one local folder](https://superuser.com/q/1809121/213663)

Comment: This works! Thank you very much.