# Get FileZilla to ignore remote folders and just download all files in the hierarchy to one local folder

Tags: filezilla, files-folders

How can I get FileZilla to ignore folders and just show the files in the hierarchy?

I want to be able to download all the files in a complex hierarchy of folders (specifically, the `Uploads` of a Wordpress site) but without the hierarchy. I.e. I want all the files to arrive in just one folder (that has no sub-folders) at my destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Open *File search* window (from toolbar or from menu *Server > Search remote files*);
- Select *Remote search* function and unselect *Find directories* to generate a list of all remote files;
- Select all found files;
- Right click, and select *Download*;
- Select *Flatten remote paths, download all contained files directly into target directory*.

---

Similarly for uploads:
[FileZilla: Whats the best way to synch several folders into one?](https://superuser.com/q/1517520/213663)

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. I don't have a toolbar icon, but "Search remote files..." is available on the Server drop-down menu.